# After installing mongo db in my project with express js i am mongo db is not connecting why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database-connection

Please help me to find the what is mean by connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: can you show us the code that connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windowsOs then go to task manager -> services -> click on mongodb -> click on services button on the right bottom of the tab -> click on start .. this should restart your mongodb server and fix the issue.

If you are using a command prompt/ terminal then just restart your mongodb server.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgpGmi0EgcA
This video might help.